# amount field with decimals in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have a SQl with an amount field like,

to_char(ERR_VW.GROSS_AMT,'$999,999,999.99') GROSS_AMT,

But when I execute this thru hibenrate, i get the foll exception

```
Wrapped exception:
java.sql.SQLException: Fail to convert to internal representation
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:138)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:175)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:240)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.CharCommonAccessor.getBigDecimal(CharCommonAccessor.java:325)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSetImpl.getBigDecimal(OracleResultSetImpl.java:1513)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSet.getBigDecimal(OracleResultSet.java:2099)
    at org.hibernate.type.BigDecimalType.get(BigDecimalType.java:46)
    at org.hibernate.type.NullableType.nullSafeGet(NullableType.java:184)
    at org.hibernate.type.NullableType.nullSafeGet(NullableType.java:210)
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader$ScalarResultColumnProcessor.extract(CustomLoader.java:501)
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader$ResultRowProcessor.buildResultRow(CustomLoader.java:447)
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.getResultColumnOrRow(CustomLoader.java:344)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:647)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:745)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:270)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2294)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2172)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2167)
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.list(CustomLoader.java:316)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:1832)
    at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.list(AbstractSessionImpl.java:165)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SQLQueryImpl.list(SQLQueryImpl.java:179)
```

How do i handle them?

Comment: to_char() will give you a String and not a BigDecimal.

Comment: Yes i want a string value like "$123.89"...

Comment: It looks like Hibernate is trying to map that to a BigDecimal.  Change your entity/pojo value for this from a BigDecimal to a String.